# SQL LEFT JOIN - Inner select not returning columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called 'Customers' and 'Orders'. Tables column names are as follow:

```
Customers: id, name, address
Orders: id, person_id, product, price
```

The desired outcome is to query all customers with one of their latest purchases. I have a lot of duplicates in 'Orders' table whereby two records with same time-stamp due to some bug.

I have written the following code but the issue is that the query does not return table 2(Orders) column values. Can anyone advise what the issue is?

---

```
SELECT C.Id,C.Name, O.item, O.price, O.product
FROM Customers C
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 person_id
        FROM Orders 
        WHERE status = 'Pending'
    ) O ON C.ID = O.person_id
```

---

```
Results:  O.item, O.price, O.product values are all null
```

Edit: Sample Data

ID/ NAME/   ADDRESS/        
1/  A/  Ad1/        
2/  B/  Ad2/        
3/  C/  Ad3/

ID/ Person ID/  PRODUCT PRICE/  Created Date
ID-1234/    1/  Book/   $5/ 26-2-2017
ID-1235/    1/  Book/   $5/ 26-2-2017
ID-1236/    2/  Calendar/   $10/    4-2-2017
ID-1238/    1/  Pen/    $2/ 1-1-2016

Comment: MySQL doesnt support `TOP`. Are you sure you are using mysql?

Comment: I am using SQL.

Comment: What does the `Orders.ID` column actually contain?  Does it contain numbers as text, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `id` column in `Orders` is a primary key autoincrement, then the following should work:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.name,
       COALESCE(t1.price, 0.0) AS price,
       COALESCE(t1.product, 'NA') AS product
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders t1
    ON c.id = t1.person_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT person_id, MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(id, 4, LEN(id)) AS INT)) AS max_id
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY person_id
) t2
    ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id AND
       t2.max_id    = CAST(SUBSTRING(t1.id, 4, LEN(t1.id)) AS INT)
```

This answer assumes that taking the greatest order ID per customer will yield the most recent purchase.  Ideally you should have a timestamp column which captures when a transaction took place.  Note that even in the query above, we still have no way of knowing *when* the most recent transaction took place.

Comment: Thanks. Should the second JOIN be 'LEFT JOIN' or 'JOIN'? When I tried 'LEFT JOIN', I got Key Violation error. When I tried JOIN, records from Table 1 without any orders are missing.

Comment: You never answered my question.  _What_ is being stored in the `Orders.ID` column?  Numbers as text, or something else?

Comment: Sorry. Order.id is TEXT string.

Comment: @Hue Yes, but is it a number or something else?

Comment: It is a combination of number and character. Eg; ID-1234

Comment: And does the numerical portion map to the person ID?  Please update your question with sample data.

Comment: Hi @Tim I have added the sample data. To answer your question, ID in Orders table has no relation to Table 1. It is just an incremental number prefix with ID. I am almost there except some missing records. For example, in my result, Person 3 row is missing.

Comment: I updated my answer to correctly use the numerical portion of the order ID.  It requires a substring and cast operation.  Use left joins here to retain all customer data.

Comment: I am getting this error "The substring function requires 3 argument(s)."

Comment: I gave you a MySQL answer, try it again after my edit.  Please tag with your actual database for future reference.

Comment: Thanks. Once I change back to LEFT JOIN, I get key violation error. I still can't figure out what really is the issue.

Comment: I think your data has a problem.  Perhaps you inserted two records which have the same primary key value somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So where is the `timestamp` column? It's not mentioned in your table schema. But your description does not mention the `status` column either, and that is clearly in there.
Is `orders.id` unique? Is it the key for the `Orders` table?> If it is, then your schema has no way to identify "duplicate" records. You cannot mean to imply that only one order per customer is allowed, so if there are multiple orders for a single customer, how do we identify the duplicates? By the unmentioned `timestamp` column?

If there IS a `timestamp column, and that's how you would identify dupes, then use it.

```
SELECT C.Id,C.Name, O.item, O.price, O.product
FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN Orders o
   on o.id = (Select Min(id) from orders
              where person_id = c.Id
                and timestamp = o.timestamp
                and status = 'Pending')
```

Comment: timestam is 'created date' column which I did not mention here. There is no way I can identified duplicates as they are the same except ID from Orders table. Can I use Min/Max for text string as ID column is a text string.